# How to use two ease-in-out effects for two different css properties?

Tags: html, css, class, transition, opacity

I cant figure out how to easy-in-out the opacity AND the translate-y of a div at the same time.
If i use transition: transform 1s ease-in-out; and Transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out for the same div it doesnt work so I can only ease-in-out one of the c
CSS properties at the same time.

This is my HTML of the div:

```
<div id="box1" class="normal">

        <h2>Home</h2>

</div>
```

And I use Jquery to change the class on click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".normal").click(function(){
                    var thisobj =  $(this);
                    if(thisobj.hasClass("active"))
                    {
                        $(this).removeClass("active");
                    }else
                    {
                        $(this).addClass("active");
                    }
                });
            });
```

This is my CSS:

```
.normal{position: fixed;
z-index: 20;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 35%;
background-image:url(images/box1.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
top: 62%;
transform: translateY(0%);
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.active{ position: fixed;
z-index: 20;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 35%;
background-image:url(images/box1.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
top: 62%;
transform: translateY(-105%);
filter: alpha(opacity=1);
-moz-opacity: 1;
-khtml-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.normal:hover{
position: fixed;
z-index: 20;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 35%;
background-image:url(images/box1.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
top: 62%;
transform: translateY(-10%);
filter: alpha(opacity=1);
-moz-opacity: 1;
-khtml-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
```

}

```
.active:hover{
position: fixed;
z-index: 20;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 35%;
background-image:url(images/box1.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px -1px 34px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
top: 62%;
transform: translateY(-105%);
transition: transform 1.0s ease;
filter: alpha(opacity=1);
-moz-opacity: 1;
-khtml-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
```

}

So the ease works for the translate-y but I dont know how to add a second ease-in-out effect for a different property...

I want to ease the opacity in and out if you hover over the .normal.

I hope that one of you guys can help me.
This is the website that im working on:
http://www.felixgeerts.tk
Im 16 years old and from the Netherlands so dont mind my bad English please. :)

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Change your `transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;` to `transition: all 1s ease-in-out;`. See if that helps

Answer (score 0):

The `transition` code is only referring to the `transform` attribute, set the `transition` to `all` and see if that works.